# Opengl object translations

Tags: java, opengl, position, translation

I'm working on my school project with opengl in which im supposed to create a "basic scene" using some provided models and my own ideas. 
I will create a simple farm: made already a house from vertices and put a cat model in front of it...but here is my concern:

As I started coding I realised every model is chained to the previous model matrix? for example piece of the code:

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    final GL3 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL3();
    loader.setUniformMatrix("projection", projection);

    gl.glClear(GL3.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL3.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    myTexture.bind(gl, modeling, "my_texture");

    myTexture.bind(gl, program, "my_texture");

    Mat4 mv = MatrixMath.lookAt(this.eyeX,this.eyeY,this.eyeZ,this.at,this.up);

    program.setUniformMatrix("model_view", mv);
    program.use(gl);
    vbo.bind(gl);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL3.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices);
    // 2nd part
    mouseMv = mv;
    modeling.setUniformMatrix("model_view", mouseMv);
    Mat4 translate = MatrixMath.translate(1.0f, 0.35f, 0);
    Mat4 rotate = MatrixMath.rotationX(-270.0f);
    mouseMv = mouseMv.mul(translate);
    mouseMv = mouseMv.mul(rotate);

    angle += 2.0f;
    if (angle > 360.0f)
    angle -= 360.0f;

    rotate = MatrixMath.rotationZ(angle);
    mouseMv = mouseMv.mul(rotate);
    modeling.setUniformMatrix("model_view", mouseMv);
    modeling.use(gl);
        for (Map.Entry<String, VertexBufferObject> entry : vboHashMap.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            entry.getValue().bind(gl);
            gl.glDrawArrays(GL3.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, SGFLoader.getNumVertices(key));
        }
}
```

(very sry for the 'simple framework' we need to use...it does not allow me to work with tutorials provided in the net)

```
Mat4 mv = MatrixMath.lookAt(this.eyeX,this.eyeY,this.eyeZ,this.at,this.up);

program.setUniformMatrix("model_view", mv);
```

I create a 'look at matrix' which allows me to put the eye on the camera look at given point . now it's (0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

After that when i draw my house from vertices it is put at the given points (rectangle centered around (0.0, 0.0, 0.0));

When i want to put the model of the mouse I'm using last transformed matrix of previous object to put it in reference to it (in this case i use mv matrix [i took it from class examples]);  Can i put it in any other place without need to reference for previous object? In the tutorials i found they were using matrix push and matrix pop to get to different objects.   I wanted to control the mouse movement, and by pressing keyboard buttons move it around the scene, but it had no success. I tried to multiply the mouseMv by a translation matrix but it didn't change it position. Any suggestions how i can make the mouse 'controllable' and movable in the scene?

When i create a new matrix for mouseMv, the object is not visible.

This is my concern. When i will create lots of objects on my scene they will have to refer to the previous object that was created.

Answer (score 1):

Try to understand transformation matrices as a series of transformations condensed into a single entity. You can chain transformations with matrices. You start with a lookAt matrix we call `view`.

Then for each model you have own model matrix, for example `model_transform_mouse`, `model_transform_cat` and so on. The modelview compound matrix is the result of the multiplication of view with the model transform

```
modelview = view · model_transform_
```

So create one universal lookAt matrix and then for each model you create a new modelview matrix by first copying that view matrix and multiplying the model transform onto it.

```
Mat4 view = MatrixMath.lookAt(this.eyeX,this.eyeY,this.eyeZ,this.at,this.up);

Mat4 model_transform_cat = ...
Mat4 modelview_cat = view.mul(model_transform_cat); //assuming Mat4::mul does not modify the calling instance
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL has a stack mechanism that allows you to save transformation matrices at certain points. You should look at making judicious use of `glPushMatrix()` and `glPopMatrix()` to position each element of your scene exactly the way you want.